# input field not getting disabled or enables as desired

Tags: javascript

I am having two input fields. I want to disable the second input field if unless I enter something in first text field. Second input field should get enabled as soon as I enter something in first textfield. Currently I am trying to do it like this but it is not working as desired.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<input type="text" id="value1" />
<input type="text" id="value2" />

<script>
    var val1 = Number(document.getElementById('value1').value)
    var val2 = Number(document.getElementById('value2').value)
    if(document.getElementById('value1').value===null ||document.getElementById('value1').value===''){
            document.getElementById('value2').disabled = true 
        }
        else{document.getElementById('value2').disabled = false }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I am very new to javascript. I need some help here.

Comment: How is it working right now? What's the failure you're encountering?

Comment: @HoriaComan it's not working because there are no event handlers.... they need to be attached to keydown on the text boxes

Comment: @CallumLinington yup, you should write that as an answer. Completely missed it :D

Comment: Currently it disables the second field and nothing happens when I enter something in first field.

Comment: Write an onchange event, and corresponding method to do the above logic. that's it

Comment: @PSo keydown is better, because then you can take into account the backspace

Comment: If a user writes something in first field and then backspaces to deletes all of it then second field should get disabled again

Comment: Yeah don't worry ArbitB, you question is clear enough! It is a keydown event

Comment: @CallumLinington checked, only keyup event is working as expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The anwser should be working now:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<input type="text" id="value1" onkeyup="myFunction()"/>
<input type="text" id="value2" disabled="disabled" />

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var val1 = Number(document.getElementById('value1').value)
  var val2 = Number(document.getElementById('value2').value)
  if(document.getElementById('value1').value===null ||document.getElementById('value1').value===''){
    document.getElementById('value2').disabled = true 
  }else {
    document.getElementById('value2').disabled = false 
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add an [event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) and check the 1st field value to change the state of the second one:

```js
var val1 = document.getElementById('value1');

val1.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
    document.getElementById('value2').disabled = val1.value === "";
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="value1" />
<input type="text" id="value2" disabled />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="value1"  onblur="Call()"/>
<input type="text" id="value2" />
<script>
    var val1 = Number(document.getElementById('value1').value)
    var val2 = Number(document.getElementById('value2').value)
    document.getElementById('value2').disabled = true

function Call()
{
     if(document.getElementById('value1').value===null ||document.getElementById

('value1').value===''){
            document.getElementById('value2').disabled = true 
        }
        else{document.getElementById('value2').disabled = false }
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```